# 5 hours transit at KBP airport (Ukraine), do I need a visa?

Tags: transit, ukraine, iraqi-citizens, kbp

I'll travel from Minsk to Dubai by through KBP airport (Ukraine) and will change plane within 5 hours transit (I'm not going to leave the transit zone), Do I need a visa in this case? I am Iraqi with an Iraqi passport.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kyiv Boryspil airport has an international transfer area, so there's no need to go through passport and customs control between your flights. See "International to International Connections" on [airport website](https://kbp.aero/en/pass/transfer/):

> International to International Connections
> If you arrive at Boryspil airport on an international flight and proceed to the international departure you go through aviation security control at the second level of terminal D and proceed to the third level directly to the gate.

> If you do not have your connecting boarding pass, please go to the Transfer desk located at the second level of terminal D. Our friendly staff will issue a boarding pass for your onward flight.

Answer (score 0):

No, in Ukraine you don't need a visa to switch from one flight to another in the same airport without leaving the transit area.  Arguably that's the main point of a transit area: you don't officially enter the country the airport is in.

As a comment points out, in some other countries (e.g. the EU) you might need a transit visa (as an Iraqi, not applicable to all nationalities).  But not in Ukraine.

Comment: This is, at least in general, not correct. It is not uncommon that you need some kind of visa even if you are only transiting at an airport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I added some clarifications that my answer relates to OP's question about Ukraine, and is not applicable to every country.